# -bash: Setting: command not found

Tags: bash, terminal, command

Every time I open the terminal I get this message:

```
Last login: Sun May  5 18:30:40 on ttys000
-bash: Setting: command not found
Marcos-MacBook-Pro:~ (myname)$
```

As you can see there is there is an issue with my bash_profile:

```
-bash: Setting: command not found
```

I believe that this is happened since I've accidentally modified the file using the `vim` command.

I'll post the modified .bash_profile file hoping that wil be easy for you to spot if there is anything wrong whit it:

```
Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

alias python=python3
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
".bash_profile" 7L, 188C
```

I can't really see anything wrong with it but I'm new on the terminal. Maybe there is a way to reset the file to default?

Comment: Take a look at second line of your .bash_profile.

Comment: You don't need to `export PATH`; your shell is already getting it from the environment. The alias should go in `.bashrc`, as it is only intended for interactive shells and won't be inherited from your initial login shell. (Since `macOS` terminal emulators typically aren't started *from* a shell session, it's good practice to source `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to comment the first line of your `.bash_profile` as right now it's trying to use `Setting` as a bash declaration.

Your `.bash_profile` should be:

```sh
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

alias python=python3
```